# Printing an array of list horizontally

Tags: c#, arrays

There was a question related to this one in regards to printing a list of an array horizontally. I was able to do so, but it also repeated the name I had as well. How can I get rid of that?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] testScore1 = { 99, 67, 98, 78, 56 };
        int[] testScore2 = { 88, 78, 54, 23 };
        int[] testScore3 = { 77, 67, 55 };

        foreach (int i in testScore1)
        {
            Console.Write("Morgan: " + i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

I just want "Morgan" to be printed out once rather than "Morgan: number" "Morgan: number" and so on. Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print the name outside the loop so that it is not repeated:

```
int[] testScore1 = { 99, 67, 98, 78, 56 };
int[] testScore2 = { 88, 78, 54, 23 };
int[] testScore3 = { 77, 67, 55 };
Console.Write("Morgan: "); // Note the print here
foreach (int i in testScore1)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine(); // this adds a new line at the very end so you can print another person's scores on a new line
```

Answer (score 0):

"Morgan" repeats because you do it inside a `foreach` loop. The purpose of a `foreach` loop is to repeat the same task over and over. If you want to do something only once, then don't put it inside a loop. Instead, put an appropriate `Console.Write()` call outside the loop.

Comment: @QuangP. As you can see, you cannot format code in a comment. Please post a new question instead.

Comment: @QuangP. Note, you still need a loop to print the elements of the array. It often helps to write the steps in words before trying to write any code. For example, in this case the steps could be: 1. Print the name. 2. Print the test scores. You can do Step 1 with a single `Console.Write()`. Step 2 requires a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Console.Write("Morgan: " + i);` to outside of foreach loop.

You get repeated prints because its inside the foreach loop and it it called 5 times as list of element is 5.